# Magento 2.3.4 installation error on Xampp winodws 10

Tags: magento2.3.4, xampp, windows10

Getting following error,

Running Magento Commands return : **Class Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Proxy does not exist**

[image]

How to install Magento 2 on xampp windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any of the following steps?

1. Go to the file in this path

> /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php

and change the line *138* with

`$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));`

2. search for a file called

> gd2.php

go to line *100* and replace it with this line

```
if ($url && isset($url['scheme']) && !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes) && !is_file($filename)) {
            return false;
        }
```

3. go to the Database that houses your Magento tables and run this SQL query

   INSERT INTO core_config_data (path, value) VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0)
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;
4. Composer install
5. If none of the above steps work then you should probably check this issue thread out and it might be of some use https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29197. From what I gathered, the issue may be that the permissions of some of your folders aren't correct or are placed in the wrong folder causing Magento to fail because it can't find or read the files that it needs to run properly.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: @zus is the error showing any different? or is it the same error?

Comment: same error, https://justpaste.it/63hoa

Comment: @zus What command were you running before you got this error?

Comment: no, just try to install magento on localhost,  localhost/magento getting the above error.

Comment: @zus i will update my answer with a few more steps to follow and inform me if it the problem persists